# Can we and should we create MongoID for nested objects inside document?

Tags: mongodb

We have a collection of documents, each document has an array of objects

```
 {
      "_id":_MONGO_ID_,
      "property":"value",
      "list":[{...}, {...},  ...]
 }
```

But each object of the list also needs a unique id for the needs of our app.

```
 {"id":213456789, "somestuff":"somevlue" ...}
```

We do not wish to create a collection for these objects because they are small and would rather store them straight into the document.

Now the question. Right now we generate a unique id based on time which looks like the MongoID. We need an id to make it easier to target each object. Would it be a good idea to generate a MongoID for each object of the list instead? Any pros and cons?

Comment: _"Would it be a good idea to generate a MongoID for each object of the list instead?"_ That depends upon your application requirement. Does your application has such a requirement? Does that id aid in CRUD operations on the `list` field? Do you mean `ObjectId` , when you are referring `MongoID`?

Comment: Do the list items need their own identity?

Comment: We use the id to do operations outside of MongoDB. We just need a unique ID. But we do not search for that id in any of our queries.

Comment: @KevinSmith yes each object needs a unique id

Comment: @prasad_ Yes ObjectId of Mongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is wise to separate DB-specific resources from business/data domain resources.  You always want to be able to manipulate the data completely independent of the host database and the drivers associated therewith.   `ObjectId()` is relatively lightweight and in fact a BSON type, separate from the MongoDB core objects, but for true arms-length separation and an easier physical implementation, I would recommend a simple string instead.  If you don't have extreme space/scale issues, UUIDv4 is good way to get a unique string.